# Get original value from HASH

Tags: hash, passwords, oracle10g

I came across a table the other day on our enterprise system -- dba_users (oracle).

I was able to find a hashed password in this table for each employee, and also their username.

As far as I know (from googling) the username + password is concatenated, then hashed.

Question: knowing the "salt" (my own username), the "original value" (my own password), and also the hashed value...is there a danger here of being able to figure-out the hash?

Also -- googling oracle 10g hash -- seems like some folks think they've figured the hash algorythm out.  And I've read about "rainbow tables" and "offline dictionary attacks"...  And finally, I've googled oracle 11g, and one of the features in that version is they hide the hashed password in dba_users so end-users can't see it.

Anyway, I'm scratching my head over why I (i.e., end-users) have access to this table, and why the DBA dosen't seem too worried about it.

Comment: select REGEXP_SUBSTR(DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('USER','USER'), '''[^'']+''') PASSWD from dual;

Which hash algorithm do Oracle use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of hashing the password and then storing the hash to database is that if you do so you won't have to worry about who can see the password in the table.

To emphasize: a (properly calculated) hash value of a password which is stored in database is completely useless without the original.

As far as I know, for algorithms like md5, there isn't a way to reverse engineer the original password from hash whatsoever. That's why most services nowadays don't send you your password when you click 'I forgot' link - instead they offer to set a new one (as soon as you provide the old password and the service compares hashes).

Comment: Unsalted MD5 can be very easily brute-forced these days, especially with rainbow tables. Use of a stronger (salted) hash such as SHA-1, at a minimum, is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks @GoranJovic.  For one record in that table (mine), I do know the original value (my own password).

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on what @Goran Jovic said, by concatenating (ie salting) each hashed password with the username.There is no danger in making this available. To make sense of this, you have to understand how a rainbow table work. The way a series of passwords is cracked with a rainbow table is by loading up a precomputed series of hashes from passwords into memory. Then, searching through the table of hashes associated unknown passwords to see if you can find a match in the rainbow table (of which you know the password corresponding with a specific hash). By salting the hashes with a unique identifier (ie a username), however, you defeat this attack because even a password that's already been seen will hash differently depending n the user associated with it. Therefore now, instead of a rainbow table having to handle the millions of different password combinations possible, it must now contain a hash of every possible password plus every possible username. The results space of this is simply too large to search and unless there was a quantum leap in computing technology impossible to beat using a bruteforce tactic.